# Error when using 'fitdist()" function in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-fitting, weibull, fitdistrplus

I would like to fit a Weibull distribution to my data using fitdist() function from the fitdistrplus package in R. My data in split into bins, and the fitting needs to happen in each bin. However, I have some bins with only one data value and fitdist() function doesn't like that. I was wondering if there is a way to "tell" fitdist() not to fit in that bin - I'm thinking something similar to what it's done to avoid negative values, i.e fitdist(x[x > 0], "weibull").

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1.55752015113831, 1.86181771755219, 1.3730936050415, 
1.47793698310852, 1.66031086444855, 1.31968522071838, 1.19886374473572, 
1.63071382045746, 1.79910719394684, 1.83555865287781, 2.51496362686157, 
2.77573442459106, 2.41649007797241, 2.16212272644043, 2.20722556114197, 
2.22031855583191, 2.56367325782776, 2.23889565467834, 2.06307983398438, 
2.04429388046265), X2 = c(5.96779193297146, 6.0423492582171, 
0.145518317755237, 0.156240204303897, 0.0690296680870719, 6.24221097591206, 
6.12635547901035, 6.17154346375459, 0.00877351789515712, 6.18053695875579, 
6.10040350681974, 6.04536502183551, 6.16195714909474, 6.13228633875795, 
6.10040350681974, 5.9043000420551, 6.05266261585455, 5.98250856115524, 
5.84601250054097, 5.85279344130853), X3 = c(35, 35, 1, 1, 1, 
36, 36, 36, 1, 36, 35, 35, 36, 36, 35, 34, 35, 35, 34, 34), X4 = c(2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008)), row.names = 31249:31268, class = "data.frame")
```

The way I fit the Weibull distribution is as follows:

```
MLE<- aggregate(data$X1, by = list(data$X3), FUN = function(x) fitdist(x[x > 0], "weibull")$estimate)
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example? How to help you will depend a whole lot on what you mean by "my data is split into bins". Is your data in a `list`, with each bin a different list item? Or are you using base functions like `tapply`, or `dplyr` or `data.table` or something else...? The best way to get help is to share a little bit of sample data in a copy/pasteable way, e.g. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` if it's a data frame. Or share code to simulate fake data in the same structure. [See this FAQ for tips on making reproducible examples in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated my question adding the first 20 rows of data and the code I use to fit the Weibull distribution.